# MJPEG streaming with libcurl

Tags: c, libcurl

I want to receive JPEG images from an IP-camera over HTTP. I am using LIBCURL for this purpose in my C program. The camera returns a single image with the following URL:

```
"http://143.205.116.14?image&res=full&x0=0&y0=0&x1=2944&y1=1920"
```

Using LIBCURL, I can receive a single image and write it to a .jpg file in the callback function. However, for continuous streaming, the camera accepts a GET request as follows:

```
"GET /mjpeg&res=full&x0=0&y0=0&x1=2944&y1=1920 HTTP/1.1\r\n HOST:143.205.16.14\r\n\r\n"
```

I was wondering how do I specify this GET request in libcurl. Is it possible to use in curl_easy_setopt()?

At present I use the following code to get a single image and save in the write_data callback function:

```
size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream) {
    size_t written;
    written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
    return written;
}

int main()
{
        curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {
    fp = fopen("C:\\trans.txt","wb");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://143.205.116.14?image&res=full&x0=0&y0=0&x1=2944&y1=1920");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data); 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    fclose(fp);
    }
```

How do I use the GET method so that the images are received continuously and saved by the callback function?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure about this, but I think you must open the connection with CURL specify that the connection will be kept alive and then start downloading data.

With some type of while() you should download data and get each JPEG that the camera sent.

You must read about MJPEG codec, which has a structure where each JPEG is delimited by a header.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the full URL?

`http://143.205.116.14/mjpeg&res=full&x0=0&y0=0&x1=2944&y1=1920`

libcurl parses this and creates the GET request. GET is the default for HTTP, you have to add some code to get HEAD or POST (so you probably don't want to do that).

Comment: I have used this full URL (for continuous stream) in the above program. But it gets stuck and doesn't capture any image.

Comment: If you use this URL in a browser, do you get anything? libcurl doesn't do anything special, it just sends the request over HTTP. You can use wireshark to check what exactly it's sending and to make sure it's the request you want. If it doesn't work in a browser, it won't work with libcurl (in most cases).